# Laravel Nova not persisting new model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, laravel-nova

I am running into a weird problem of Laravel Nova not being able to persist any of my models. Trying to save a user on a fresh Nova install and using the default User resource created still fails. (Updating a user entry works though).

The error I am getting back when trying to create a new user is:

> `No query results for model [App\User].`

Looking into Laravel Nova Core, the file responsible for this is: `vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Controllers/ResourceStoreController.php`
Inside this function, if I try to manually save a new model

```php
dd((new User())->create(['name' => '', 'email' => '', etc]));
```

it successfully outputs the model but still doesn't have it saved in the database.

The same code when placed either in Tinker / any of the other web routes, successfully creates a new model and saves it in the DB.

My `app\Nova\User.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Gravatar;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Password;

class User extends Resource
{
    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = 'App\\User';

    /**
     * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $title = 'name';

    /**
     * The columns that should be searched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $search = [
        'id', 'name', 'email',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),

            Gravatar::make(),

            Text::make('Name')
                ->sortable()
                ->rules('required', 'max:255'),

            Text::make('Email')
                ->sortable()
                ->rules('required', 'email', 'max:254')
                ->creationRules('unique:users,email')
                ->updateRules('unique:users,email,{{resourceId}}'),

            Password::make('Password')
                ->onlyOnForms()
                ->creationRules('required', 'string', 'min:8')
                ->updateRules('nullable', 'string', 'min:8'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the cards available for the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function cards(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filters available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the lenses available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function lenses(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the actions available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function actions(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**User Model**:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**My User table migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be tripping up a save operation this way? For additional info my setup is as follows:

Laravel (5.8) 
Nova (2.5) 
PHP 7.2
MySQL  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.6-MariaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the issue was with my MariaDB installation. Having recently upgraded it, I guess there may have been some configuration that caused mayhem. Moving away from MariaDB to MySQL 8 solved the issue.

Comment: Did you determine what feature was needed or different between the two db versions?  This could be handy to (1) the Laravel developers and (2) other users.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames, and no I wasn't able to determine that unfortunately. Having recently changed from mysql 5 to mariadb 10, I think there were some conflicts I didn't address properly during that switch hence the bug. That's my strong suspicion.